# How to handle multiple interdependent sagas when rendering server-side?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-saga

I am implementing server-side rendering using [redux-saga](/questions/tagged/redux-saga).

I am following the ["real world" example](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/real-world/server.js) provided in the redux-saga repository.

1. [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) entry-point uses [react.js](/questions/tagged/react.js) `renderToString` to render the application.
2. rendering the application triggers `componentWillMount`, which dispatches actions `GET_GEOLOCATION` and `GET_DATE`. These async actions will resolve with `SET_GEOLOCATION` and `SET_DATE`.
3. `renderToString` finishes rendering the application; `END` action terminates the saga listeners

The problem is that `SET_GEOLOCATION` and `SET_DATE` themselves are used to `put` a new action `GET_MOVIES`. However, by the time the `SET_GEOLOCATION` and `SET_DATE` are called, the saga listeners are no longer active (we terminated it after `renderToString`). Therefore, while `GET_MOVIES` will be dispatched, the `GET_MOVIES` action will not be picked and `SET_MOVIE` will never happen.

Server code:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory({
    initialEntries: [
      req.url
    ]
  });
  const store = configureStore(undefined, history);
  const context = {};

  const rootComponent = <Provider store={store}>
    <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.url}>
      <Route component={RootRoute} />
    </StaticRouter>
  </Provider>;

  store
    .runSaga(rootSaga).done
    .then(() => {
      const body = renderToString(rootComponent);
      const response = renderHtml(body, store);

      res
        .send(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res
        .status(500)
        .send(error.message);
    });

  // Force componentWillMount to issue saga effects.
  renderToString(rootComponent);

  store.close();
});
```

Sagas:

```
const watchNewSearchCriteria = function *(): Generator<*, *, *> {
  yield takeLatest([
    SET_GEOLOCATION,
    SET_DATE
  ], function *() {
    const {
      coordinates,
      date
    } = yield select((state) => {
      return {
        coordinates: state.movieEventsView.location ? state.movieEventsView.location.coordinates : null,
        date: state.movieEventsView.date
      };
    });

    if (!coordinates || !date) {
      return;
    }

    yield put(getMovies({
      coordinates,
      date
    }));
  });
};

const watchGetMovies = function *() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_MOVIES, function *(action) {
    const result = yield call(getMovies, action.payload);

    yield put(setMovies(result));
  });
};
```

How to delay `store.close` until after there are no sagas that are in the state other than `take`?

Comment: A simple workaround would be to fork `watchGetMovies` `takeLatest` body from within `watchNewSearchCriteria`, though this approach results in one-less abstraction.

Answer (score 7):

> How to delay `store.close` until after there are no sagas that are in the state other than `take`?

To answer my own question, I need to observe resolution of anything thats been [`put`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#putaction). I can do this using the [Saga Monitor](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#sagamonitor).

Saga Monitor can be configured at the time of creating the `redux-saga` middleware. For our use case, it needs to track whenever an action has been `put` and remove it from the index when it has been resolved/ rejected/ cancelled.

```
const activeEffectIds = [];

const watchEffectEnd = (effectId) => {
  const effectIndex = activeEffectIds.indexOf(effectId);

  if (effectIndex !== -1) {
    activeEffectIds.splice(effectIndex, 1);
  }
};

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({
  sagaMonitor: {
    effectCancelled: watchEffectEnd,
    effectRejected: watchEffectEnd,
    effectResolved: watchEffectEnd,
    effectTriggered: (event) => {
      if (event.effect.CALL) {
        activeEffectIds.push(event.effectId);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

We need to access this from the consumer of the store, therefore I assign `activeEffectIds` to the store instance:

```
store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;

store.close = () => {
  store.dispatch(END);
};

store.activeEffectIds = activeEffectIds;
```

Then instead of synchronously stopping the saga...

```
renderToString(rootComponent);
store.close();
```

we need to delay `store.close` until `store.activeEffectIds.length` is 0.

```
const realDone = () => {
  setImmediate(() => {
    if (store.activeEffectIds.length) {
      realDone();
    } else {
      store.close();
    }
  });
};

// Force componentWillMount to issue saga effects.
renderToString(rootComponent);

realDone();
```

Now `store.close` is called only when all the asynchronous effects are resolved.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to include your solution :)