# What does @redux-saga/simple-saga-monitor do?

Tags: redux, redux-saga, monitor

In the [redux-saga real-word example](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/examples/real-world) in [store/configureStore.dev.js](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/examples/real-world/store/configureStore.dev.js), a package named [@redux-saga/simple-saga-monitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@redux-saga/simple-saga-monitor) is included and added as saga middleware. Unfortunately I cannot find any information on what exactly this package does. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#sagamonitor

Comment: it allows you to do [kind of something like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/43839772/10294022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43839772/10294022)

Answer (score 0):

I was wonder about the same and not much info has been shared online but looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/packages/simple-saga-monitor), it looks like a simple wrapper to log saga activities to the window or react native app console